# Why in my first PyQt6 project the self.input.text() is not working?

Tags: python, user-interface, input, output, pyqt6

I initially created a PyQt6 form that get a name and after pressing a button, prints the name in the output Text Edit. I made it without using "QT Designer" successfully.

But then, I tried to create the same project using "QT Designer". but when I use the **self.inputField.text()** code, the app assumes the **inputField** as a function that returns Any type.
When I press the button after runing the app, the app will be closed and in the IDE output window this message appears:

**[Running] python -u "d:\4__dev\project\Python\GUI Apps\My First App\With Designer UI\demo.py"
d:\4__dev\project\Python\GUI Apps\My First App\With Designer UI\demo.py:12: DeprecationWarning: sipPyTypeDict() is deprecated, the extension module should use sipPyTypeDictRef() instead
super().**init**()

[Done] exited with code=3221226505 in 67.038 seconds**.

could you please help me out about this problem?

-The GUI file:
[Click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgCI.png)

-The Code:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout , QLineEdit, QPushButton, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt6 import uic


class MyApp(QWidget):
    

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        uic.loadUi('gui.ui', self)
        self.setWindowTitle('My App')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("info.ico"))
        self.inputField.setText("Jeff")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.sayHello)

    def sayHello(self):
        input_Text = self.inputField.text()
        self.output.setText(f'Hello {input_Text}')



if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)



myApp = MyApp()
myApp.show()


try:
    sys.exit(app.exec())
except SystemExit:
    print('Closing Window...')
```

The UI code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>299</width>
    <height>380</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="inputField">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>30</y>
     <width>241</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="placeholderText">
    <string>Enter a message...</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QTextEdit" name="output">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>120</y>
     <width>241</width>
     <height>221</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="contextMenuPolicy">
    <enum>Qt::DefaultContextMenu</enum>
   </property>
   <property name="whatsThis">
    <string>It's a textbox to print out messages for you dear user!!!</string>
   </property>
   <property name="tabChangesFocus">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="placeholderText">
    <string>output's gonna be written here</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="button">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>30</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>241</width>
     <height>41</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Say Hello</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I tried almost everything. For example:

- Trying to write it in another way.
- Trying to pass a variable to the sayHello function, but I couldn't use it.
- ...

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "the app assumes the input as a function that returns Any type". What "app", your program or the IDE? And what error do you get? We need the *exact error*, not a vague explanation of it.

Comment: In my IDE (A.K.A VS Code), when I bring my mouse on a word in the code, a popup appears that shows information about that word, in this case when I bring my mouse to the **input** word it shows: **(Function) input : Any**.

Comment: Please check my Question text again, because I made some changes in it.

Comment: We need more context: please run your program in a terminal or command prompt, then [edit] your post with the full traceback. Also eventually add the UI file. Note that `input` is a built-in command of python, and you shouldn't use it as a object name.

Comment: I changed the **input** to **inputField** and edited my post again.

Comment: It's a problem caused by a change in Python, if you can, upgrade to Python 3.12.0.

Comment: An unrelated note: you should always use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html), also [in Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-layouts.html).

Comment: I installed 3.12.0 Python and it didn't help.